# Resizing layouts dynamically with ViewFlipper

Tags: android, user-interface, android-mapview, viewflipper

I have a layout sizing issue...

I have a layout which consists of a ViewFlipper, a LinearLayout (containing a MapView), and a 2nd LinearLayout all in a vertical row.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:width="match_parent"
    android:height="match_parent" >

    <ViewFlipper
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="wrap_content" >
        // Top elements
    </ViewFlipper>

    <LinearLayout
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="match_parent" >
        // MapView
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:width="match_parent"
        android:height="wrap_content" >
        // Bottom elements
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem I'm seeing is that when I change the ViewFlipper to show a shorter view with showNext() or showPrevious(), the middle LinearLayout does not expand to fill the space.  Also, I see black/empty space left over from the previous ViewFlipper view when I change to a shorter view.

Is there a slick way to dynamically resize these elements so that the MapView layout will expand to fill all space not occupied by the ViewFlipper and bottom LinearLayout?

Comment: did you found the solution for this blank space?

Answer (score 26):

Try to add `android:measureAllChildren="false"` to your ViewFlipper

```
<ViewFlipper
     android:width="match_parent"
     android:height="wrap_content"
     android:measureAllChildren="false" >
<!-- Top elements --> 
</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: In our cases, this is also fix our blank space issue even after navigating between ViewFlipper with `showPrevious()` and `showNext()`